# Do a HTTP GET/POST inside a stored procedure on AWS RDS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I have a SQL Server on AWS RDS. What I would like to do is do a HTTP request inside a stored procedure.

The usual methods that would work on a standalone SQL Server instance don't work on AWS.

Any suggestions would be super appreciated.

Comment: Thats absolutely the wrong way to be doing it anyway. You should be doing that kind of thing inside your database. Your database is where you store your data.

Comment: T-SQL is not a generalized scripting language, do not use it as such. Write a script (AWS Lambda, or C#, or Python etc) that does this and pushes the data into SQL

Comment: I am a 25y+ coder and know this.  I have my reasons.  Just looking to see how people may have done it.

Doing an API call to "trigger" something is not breaking architecture really.  And it saves me money not having to spin up other services.  

If I have a DB with SQL Jobs, I can easily send out API calls to do something, without having the burden of running a labmda say every 2-3 secs to check the DB for an action.

Will continue to wait for suitable answers. thanks anyway.